# Oracle PL/SQL dynamic column values put to variable (Generalize Procedure)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to write a generalize procedure for several tables which has different types of columns.

In the procedure I'm passing

```
PROCEDURE DiffrencesIdentifyerProc(db_nameFirst IN VARCHAR2,
                                   db_nameSecond IN VARCHAR2,
                                   table_name IN VARCHAR2)
```

which creates a dynamic SQL statement like this:

```
'SELECT '||columnNamesS||' from '||db_nameFirst||'.'|| table_name||' minus select '||columnNamesS||' from '||db_nameSecond||'.'||table_name|| '';
```

What I need now is; in one situation

> `columnNamesS = ColomnA` and second situation same `columnNamesS = ColomnA,ColomnB`

can have single column name which contains varchar2 variable and other time it could be two columns with one varchar and one numeric in another situation two could be both varchar, like that  columnNamesS  can have several datatyped columns dynamically according to the passing paramters by the user,  is there a way to fetch those kind of values in oracle/sql and print like following

```
{"colomnName":"colomnValue"}  if multiliple colomns then
{"colomnName1":"colomnValue1","colomnName2":"colomnValue2"}
```

Key things: table name is given as a parameter and column names also,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: not helpfull comment at al